# replace text found in a file, multiple times using sed

Tags: awk, sed

how could i use sed in order to replace text from filetobeprocessed.txt,

which has names, and tel numbers perhaps in it:

```
Name3 john.D
Name6 mary.D
Name7 kelly.O
etc
```

which has text in a per line basis. The text to be found,exists in fileA.txt, and the replacement string, is found in fileB.txt.

for example, fileA.txt

may have

Name3 john.D,

and fileB.txt
may have

Person: John Diamen,

so filetobeprocessed.txt should become:

```
Person: John Diamen
Name6 mary.D
Name7 kelly.O
```

Of course, since file to be processed, fileA, and fileB are huge, we may have any character found in the search string, and in the replacement string, so my example is kind of basic, and does not cover all characters that exist in filetobeprocessed.txt
So i need a way, to use sed, to do a search and replace, but do this, for each line found in fileA.txt, and its equivalent string, found in the same number line, in fileB.txt

something with sed -f -

combined with

```
sed -i 's/old/new/g'
```

or

sed 's/\string to be replaced\b/replacement string/g' file.xml

what i cannot find, is a way to use this for each line of the fileA.txt, which has all strings to be searched for, and for each corresponding replacement line, found in fileB.txt

Comment: Please, post working examples of all 3 files mentioned along with the expected output for that data.

Comment: the reason for not adding a very specific example, is that i would like, a very general answer, that has to do with the issue of find each string found in line x of fileA.txt, and replace it, with the string found in line x, of fileB.txt (exact match)

Comment: how do you match fileA and fileB entries, is there a key that joins them or is it positional (first to first, second to second etc)

Answer (score 0):

In awk:

```
$ awk '
NR==FNR {               # hash the first file to a
    a[$0]=$0; next }
{
    if(FNR in b) {      # process the third file to b
        b[b[FNR]]=$0
        delete b[FNR] }
    else b[FNR]=$0      # process the second file to b
}
END {                   # after all files are processed and in memory
    for(i in a)         # go thru all entries of first file
        if(i in b)      # if entry found in second file
            print b[i]  # replace with the value of third file
        else 
            print a[i]  # otherwise print the entry from the first file
}' filetobeprocessed.txt fileA.txt fileB.txt  # mind the order
Name6 mary.D
Person: John Diamen
Name7 kelly.O
```

Comment: i do not understand how i could use the above command, for example, what foo bar baz are?  an example with my filenames, could be better for me to undesrtand

Comment: @nutame Work in progress. Done.

Comment: used it, but it should also prnt, from file to be processed, all lines that were not substituted, that are left intact. now the result file, has size 5mb, while the original one was 19mb...

Comment: Hmm, it did at least for the test data you provided. Duplicates do get removed as I hash them all to `a`.

Answer (score 0):

requirements not clear but something like this might work.

Sample files

```
==> file <==
Name1 2377
Name2 2910
Name3 8458
Name4 1522
Name5 5855
Name6 1934
Name7 8106
Name8 1735
Name9 4849
Name10 1518

==> fileA <==
Name3
Name7

==> fileB <==
Person: John Smith
Person: Mr Brown



$ awk -F'\t' 'NR==FNR {a[$1]=$2; next} 
              $1 in a {$1=a[$1]}1' <(paste fileA fileB) FS='[[:space:]]' file

Name1 2377
Name2 2910
Person: John Smith 8458
Name4 1522
Name5 5855
Name6 1934
Person: Mr Brown 8106
Name8 1735
Name9 4849
Name10 1518
```

this assumes lookup files `fileA` and `fileB` are not too large, where as there is no limitation on the to be replaced `file`

The same can be done with `sed`, assuming no special chars in the replaced texts

```
$ sed -f <(paste fileA fileB | sed -r 's_(.*)\t(.*)_s/\1/\2/_') file
```